# How to check shape of a mouse cursor on a webpage in ruby with Selenium

Tags: ruby, web, mouseover

Question says it all. I'm writing unit tests for a ruby web project (using the PageObject gem, if there's any functionality in there that can help me, and am also using Selenium for these tests). I need to check if the mouse cursor changes to a pointing hand when hovering over a link.

Is there any way to check this in ruby? Possibly by using mouseover or a similar function? I'm not too familiar with it

I know this sounds like a stupid question, but I'm required to write a test like this for a project

Comment: Assuming the tests will be run on google chrome, but they may be run on another browser.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there isn't a well-supported way to test the mouse cursor in Selenium. I think the closest you'll get is to take a screenshot and look for the cursor you want at the cursor's location in the image, which is of course a bit awkward.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and solve it with hacky-js-based solution. It's not perfect, but, as already said, Selenium (until this moment) doesn't provide a way to check mouse cursor shape.

So...

Use JavaScriptExecutor to execute JS on specific element:

```
 tagName = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].tagName" , element)
```

Combine it with specific method that will return you the css of the mouse

```
$('*').mouseenter(function(){
    var currentCursor = $(this).css('cursor') ;

    //do what you want here, for example return or console.log()
    console.log( currentCursor );
});
```